# How to make a textbox not defualt to the first vaule in a database?

Tags: ms-access-2007

This may be something simple stupid, but its not working for me. 
I made a table of rates in Access 2007.
I made a form for the table using create, split form, and followed the wizard.
I added a "Add Record", "Delete Record" and "Exit" button to the form.
For the auto created textbox, in properties, data, defualt value, I set it to "Rate"
When I first open the form the textbox always shows the first value in the database and will edit the first value in the database if I type in it.  After I click the "Add Record" button it shows "Rate" and adds records to the end of the database.

So the question is, how do I get the textbox to read "Rate" and have it defualt to the end of the database when I first open it up I can add records?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you only want to add records? If so, you can open the form in add mode (acFormAdd) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141520(v=office.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple when using the switchboard.  New switchboard item; Open Form in ADD Mode > Put in forms name.  This would open the form at a new record.
Prgammically you can use docmd.openform eg: docmd.OpenForm(form_Name,acNormal,,,acFormAdd).

**See Link in Remou's comment**

HTH

Roger